# How to check IRQ latency in Linux (X86_64) for performance tuning?

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, x86-64, interrupt, cpu-architecture

Is there a way to check the interrupt processing latency in Linux kernel?

Or is there a way to check why CPU usage is only 40% in a specific configuration of Linux 4.19.138?

---

**Background:**

Currently I met a problem, I had a X86 server running either a 3rd party Linux-4.19.138 kernel (whose configuration file is about 6000 lines) or Ubuntu 20.04 X86_64 (whose configuration file is about 9500 lines long).

When running netperf test on this server , I found with the 3rd-party Linux-4.19.138 kernel, the IO latency of netperf is worse than with Ubuntu 20.04. The CPU usage is below 40% when running the 3rd party kernel, while it is about 100% when running Ubuntu 20.04.

They are using the same kernel command line and same performance profile in kernel runtime.
It seemed that the interrupt or the netserver process in the server is throttled in Linux-4.19.138.

Then, I rebuilt Ubuntu 20.04 kernel by using the short configuration file (6000 lines long), and got the similar bad results.

So it concluded that the kernel configuration made the difference.

Before comparing the 2 configurations (6000 lines vs 9500 lines), to narrow it down, my ask is, is there a way to check why CPU usage is only 40% in that configuration of 4.19.138? Or is there a way to check the interrupt processing latency in Linux kernel ?

Comment: The number of lines in a kernel config file doesn't really tell us anything at all about *which* config options might have been set to what.  The longer one probably said "yes" to some top-level options that require answers to a bunch more questions, but that could just be drivers.  It's about as useful as talking about the colors of 2 different cars when the thing you're interested in is how well they handle corners.

Comment: It's unclear, to me, why you bring the CPU usage and interrupts latency into the question. Ubuntu is probably using a newer kernel with more support for the hardware in your server (either in terms of optimizations or technologies). BTW, using a diff tool should speed up the comparing of the two config files.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Sorry for not being clear. Let me clarify. Firstly, we found the Linux-4.19.138 is worse than Ubuntu 20.04. Then we got/built/installed the official Linux-4.19.138 in Ubuntu 20.04. After that, we only checked the testing results by changing the configuration in Ubuntu's 4.19.138, to check which one matters. We found when the CPU usage is 100%, netperf latency is better. If the CPU usage is 30-40%, the netperf latency is bad, so we focused on how to boost the CPU usage. I found the reason, let me answer this question separately

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason. It is from the
net.core.busy_read and
net.core.busy_poll are both to 0.
That means the socket polling is disabled, which impacts the netperf latency.

But the question changed to
In this case, the lower CPU usage is a sign that there is something different in Linux, what kind of tool or how can we should figure out what causes the CPU usage difference in 2 kernels?

Comment: In general, try perf first.